# DATE ADD function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic

I currently have the following code in Microsoft SQL Server to get users that viewed on two days in a row.

```
WITH uservideoviewvideo (date, user_id) AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT date, user_id 
  FROM clickstream_videos
  WHERE event_name ='video_play'  
    and user_id IS NOT NULL
) 
SELECT currentday.date AS date, 
       COUNT(currentday.user_id) AS users_view_videos, 
       COUNT(nextday.user_id) AS users_view_next_day 
FROM userviewvideo currentday
  LEFT JOIN userviewvideo nextday 
         ON currentday.user_id = nextday.user_id AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, 
currentday.date) = nextday.date
GROUP BY currentday.date
```

I am trying to get the DATEADD function to work in PostgreSQL but I've been unable to figure out how to get this to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the column `date` defined as `date` or `timestamp`?  If it's `date`, then `date + 1` will do it for you.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think PostgreSQL really has a DATEADD function. Instead, just do:

`+ INTERVAL '1 day'`

> SQL Server:
>
> Add 1 day to the current date November 21, 2012
> `SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE());` # 2012-11-22 17:22:01.423
>
> PostgreSQL:
>
> Add 1 day to the current date November 21, 2012
> `SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day';`   # 2012-11-22 17:22:01
> `SELECT CURRENT_DATE + 1;`   # 2012-11-22 17:22:01

http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd

EDIT:

It might be useful if you're using a dynamic length of time to create a string and then cast it as an interval like:

`+ (col_days || ' days')::interval`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date + 1` to do the equivalent of `dateadd()`, but I do not think that your query does what you want to do.

You should use window functions, instead:

```
with plays as (
  select distinct date, user_id
    from clickstream_videos
   where event_name = 'video_play' 
     and user_id is not null
), nextdaywatch as (
  select date, user_id, 
         case
           when lead(date) over (partition by user_id
                                     order by date) = date + 1 then 1
           else 0
         end as user_view_next_day
    from plays
)
select date, 
       count(*) as users_view_videos,
       sum(user_view_next_day) as users_view_next_day
  from nextdaywatch
 group by date
 order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of postgres 16 [`DATE_ADD()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) now exists.

In your example, you could use

```
DATE_ADD(currentday.date, '1 day')
```

From the documentation:

> `date_add ( timestamp with time zone, interval [, text ] )` → timestamp with time zone
>
> Add an interval to a timestamp with time zone, computing times of day and daylight-savings adjustments according to the time zone named by the third argument, or the current TimeZone setting if that is omitted. The form with two arguments is equivalent to the timestamp with time zone + interval operator.
>
> `date_add('2021-10-31 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz, '1 day'::interval, 'Europe/Warsaw')` → 2021-10-31 23:00:00+00