# Add/subtract date from date time format in dbplyr

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, dbplyr

I'm using dbplyr to access data in my database and I'm trying to calculate rolling sum amounts that would include all amounts from the previous 1 year. My Dates are in dttm format. I'm trying to get a table that shows 1 year prior to the Start_Date similar to below:

| Start_Date | Previous_1year |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-02 08:03:29 | 2020-07-02 08:03:29 |
| 2021-07-09 06:36:28 | 2020-07-09 06:36:28 |
| 2021-07-09 09:29:02 | 2020-07-09 09:29:02 |
| 2021-07-16 08:26:30 | 2020-07-16 08:26:30 |
| 2021-07-23 07:35:51 | 2020-07-23 07:35:51 |
| 2021-07-30 09:19:13 | 2020-07-30 09:19:13 |

I would like to subtract exactly 1 year from the Start_Date to get a rolling one-year window for each row/observation for rolling sum calculation.

I've done this in dplyr before and I would normally use the following code to get this:

```
output = df %>%
  mutate(Previous_1year = Start_Date %m+% years(-1))
```

However, this method doesn't seem to be compatible with dbplyr and my database, assuming this is because dbplyr doesn't know how to translate the code back into SQL.

I've also tried running the following code in dbplyr which I found from another question in SO:

```
output = df %>%
   mutate(Previous_1year = sql('DATEADD(y, -1, Start_Date)'))
```

but I'm getting the following error and not sure why I'm getting a invalid datetime:

```
! nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1752: XX000: [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) 
Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState XX000] ERROR:  Invalid datetime part for DATEADD().
```

Because the data is so large, I'm unable to collect all of it and do the data wrangling through dplyr to subtract 1 year from each of my Start_Date observations. So, hoping to do this within the database first so then I can do my calculations before collecting the results.

Comment: Two things: (1) I may be wrong, but I think the `dd` is a sql-server thing, does redshift prefer `day`? (2) You said one year subtraction but your adding a day instead, perhaps `dateadd(year, -1, Start_Date)`?

Comment: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html for a reference about `dd`-vs-`day`.

Comment: Thanks for the pick up @r2evans - ive fixed up my post now and corrected the mistake. It should be ``dateadd(y, -1, Start_Date)``
This is how i would add/subtract 1 year from my Start_Date in SQL but throws an error when i try doing this in dbplyr.
Also in SQL i would normal use d = day or y= year.

Comment: Do you need to cast Start_Date to datetime format first? Also, you shouldn't need the `sql`? just `mutate(Previous_1year = DATEADD(y, -1, Start_Date))`. dbplyr passes functions it doesn't know straight to the database: https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation-function.html

Comment: The error message suggests the problem occurs on execution rather than translation. Two things to try: (1) call `show_query(output)` and consider whether this produces valid SQL, you may want to post this translation to your question. (2) check the minimum date in your dataset? Subtracting 1 year from `0000-01-01` will obviously produce an invalid date.

Comment: Hi all, i ran the query again today and ```output = df %>%
   mutate(Previous_1year = sql('DATEADD(y, -1, Start_Date)'))``` is working now. Not really sure why, may have been a typo in my code or something was playing up in the database. But thank you all for replying to my questions.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Postgres, so might work on Redshift:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DBI)

pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())

df <- tbl(pg, sql("SELECT '2021-07-02 08:03:29'::timestamp AS start"))
df %>%
  mutate(previous = start - years(1))
#> # Source:   SQL [1 x 2]
#> # Database: postgres  [iangow@/tmp:5432/iangow]
#>   start               previous           
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 2021-07-02 08:03:29 2020-07-02 08:03:29
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>